# Use Panda's diff() against first column/row of data.frame

Tags: python, pandas

assume you have a dataframe where the first column is a date and the consecutive columns are values adjusted over time. F.x. the prognosis of wind for a specific date changes over time as new information is available.

My task is to compute the difference in regards to the **first** column. 
So the principle is similar to pandas.DataFrame.diff but the reference value is not the preceding column but always the first.

So assuming your dataframe looks like this

```
Date    Forecast1    Forecast2    Forecast3        
1/1/15    5             3              7
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
Date    Forecast1    Forecast2    Forecast3        
1/1/15    NaN             -2          2
```

I hope my explanation was clear.

Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [pd.DataFrame.sub](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html#pandas.DataFrame.sub) :

```
In [108]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,6,(3,3)), 
columns=['Forecast'+str(i) for i in range(1,4)],
index=pd.date_range('2016/1/1',periods=3))

In [109]: df
Out[109]: 
            Forecast1  Forecast2  Forecast3
2016-01-01          5          5          5
2016-01-02          0          3          0
2016-01-03          2          4          2

In [110]: df.sub(df.Forecast1,axis=0)
Out[110]: 
            Forecast1  Forecast2  Forecast3
2016-01-01          0          0          0
2016-01-02          0          3          0
2016-01-03          0          2          0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using [apply(..., axis=1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) applying it to rows (axis=1) instead of columns (default: axis=0):

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]:
     Date  Forecast1  Forecast2  Forecast3
0  1/1/15          5          3          7
1  2/3/15          1          4          5
2  3/4/15         10          2          1

In [79]: cols = [c for c in df.columns.tolist() if 'Forecast' in c]

In [80]: cols
Out[80]: ['Forecast1', 'Forecast2', 'Forecast3']

In [81]: df[cols].apply(lambda x: x-x[0], axis=1)
Out[81]:
   Forecast1  Forecast2  Forecast3
0          0         -2          2
1          0          3          4
2          0         -8         -9
```